2024 Community Moderator Election Results
Moderator election #2 on History has come to a close, the votes have been tallied, and the new moderator is:

They will be joining the existing crew shortly — please thank them for volunteering and share your assistance and advice with them as they learn the ropes!
For details on how the voting played out, you can download the election results here or view a summary report online.

Not sure what the etiquette is (there doesn't seem to be an equivalent post for the last time History elected mods) but I'll reply as an answer since comments are considered ephemeral.
I want to thank the community for placing this trust in me. History SE enjoys the dubious privilege of being adjacent to topics that are very relevant to current events, and highly contentious and politicized as a result.
That this is happening in parallel with the slashing of history education budgets and the rise of generative AI makes effective moderation even more critical to maintaining History SE as a useful archive of accessible history answers and a useful place to go for new knowledge.
Time to get to work!

A meta upvote of congratulations.

Congratulations to SPavel - I think the better candidate won, and to be honest, I'm rather relieved there isn't another flag queue greeting me this morning! Good luck :)

I'd like to offer a heartfelt thanks to everyone who stepped up to give our users a choice, and potentially to help keep the site clean.
As for the winner, we have your complementary mop and rubber gloves of victory waiting you! :-)
